# How to implement dynamic content render when form submited (newbie ask)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing rails 3 application (I am newbie in Rails).

Currently, I have a form (use "`form_for`") for submit, there is a `div` area under the form. What I want is when user click the '**submit**' button of the form, based on the user input data in the form, application will first go to the database to retrieve and organize some data, then the `div` area under the form will be rendered with the organized data.

That's the content of the `div` area is rendered **dynamically** based on user's input in the form, and the `div` render happens when user click "**submit**" form button .

The `index.html.haml`:

```
=form_for :myform do |form|
  = ...
  = ...
  =form.submit "submit"

%div.result
  /dynamic content to be rendered here, when user submit the form
  =render :partial 'result'
```

I think my form submission should first go to run a controller method to organize the data from Database, and what's the next step I should do? As you noticed from the above code, I have a partial there under `div`, I would like to update the '**result**' partial when user submit form, but how to implement this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*examples of how you may update your page in response to ajax polling*

```
#some_controller.rb

def your_action

end

# javascript erb file. views/some_controller/your_action.js.erb


$('div.result').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'your_action' -%>');


# _your_action.html.haml
= @dynamic_data
```

Comment: sounds like my idea too, I will try it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rails scaffolding will give you a clue on how to do this. Just include the form as partial as well in your `show` template. Something like this:

index.html.haml (or new.htm.haml):

```
= render 'new'
```

show.html.haml:

```
= render 'new'
# display your @object
```